ArduinoModbus / RS485 conflict between Serial and Serial1
I am attempting implement ArduinoModbus on my STM32 Poternta H7 using the breakout board.
Its well documented that in ArduinoRS485 that the RS485 object is hardwired. If you are using the PH7/Breakout board you need to reconfigure to make sure that the RS485 is set to Serial1/Uart1.
After i have reconfigured, when i run my code i intially can write debug messages to the Serial monitor via Serial (Onboard USB C). But once i start using RS485 on Serial1 i can no longer print to the serial monitor via Serial and the code freezes.
What i did to re configure the RS485 obj. I implemented the following based on this work around from Arduino ArduinoModbus for other shields and with different Serial port - MKR SHIELDS - Arduino Forum 1
Then saved my updated ArduinoRS485 in /lib.
In ArduinoRS485.cpp
void RS485Class::setSerial(HardwareSerial* serial) {
  _serial = serial;
}

In ArduinoRS485.h
void setSerial(HardwareSerial* serial);

In my setup code i defined;
#define UART1_TX_PIN PA_9       // J1 header 33 (LPUART) = SERIAL1_TX  = R0
 #define UART1_RX_PIN PA_10      // J1 header 35 (LPUART) = SERIAL1_RX   = DI
 #define UART1_RTS_PIN PI_14     // J1 header 37 (LPUART) = SERIAL1_RTS  = REn pin
 #define UART1_CTS_PIN PI_15     // J1 header 39 (LPUART) = SERIAL1_CTS  = DE
 #define SERIAL_PORT_HARDWARE Serial1

My ModbusClient set up
void modbusClientSetup() {
     
   while (!Serial);
     Serial.println("");
     Serial.println("Modbus RTU Client Test");
     
     RS485.setPins(UART1_TX_PIN, UART1_RX_PIN, UART1_RTS_PIN);
     RS485.setDelays(50,50);
     RS485.setSerial(&SERIAL_PORT_HARDWARE);
 
     if(!ModbusRTUClient.begin(9600,SERIAL_8N1 )){
     //Serial.println("Failed to start Modbus RTU Client!");
     while (1);
   }
 }

The line Serial.println("Modbus RTU Client Test"); works fine.
Then i run this code to test my Modbus

 void writeCoilValues() {
   
   // set the coils to 1 when counter is odd
   byte coilValue = ((counter % 2) == 0) ? 0x00 : 0x01;
 
   Serial.print("Writing Coil values ... ");
 
   // write 10 Coil values to (slave) id 1, address 0x00
   ModbusRTUClient.beginTransmission(slaveID, COILS, 0x15, 10);>   for (int i = 0; 
     i < 10; i++) {
     counter = i;
     coilValue = ((counter % 2) == 0) ? 0x00 : 0x01;
     ModbusRTUClient.write(coilValue);
     delay(100);
   
   if (!ModbusRTUClient.endTransmission()) {
     Serial.print("failed! ");
     errClient = ModbusRTUClient.lastError();
     Serial.println(errClient);
   } else {
     errClient = "All Good";
     Serial.println("success");
   }
 }

The line Serial.print("Writing Coil values ... "); does not print but the code does not freeze.
But once i get to Serial.print("failed! "); the code just freezes at write_op.wait(NULL); within USBCDC.cpp below.
bool USBCDC::send(uint8_t *buffer, uint32_t size)
 {
     lock();
 
     AsyncWrite write_op(this, buffer, size);
     _tx_list.add(&write_op);
 
     unlock();
 
     write_op.wait(NULL);
     return write_op.result;
 }

I have been stepping thru this for the last days, but i still cant find where if fails. if anyone has an idea or a better method please let me know.
Cheers


Its well documented that in ArduinoRS485 that the RS485 object is hardwired.

I don't know where you get the "well-documented" information from, both ArduinoRS485 library and ArduinoModbus library allows you to pass-in the serial port that you are going to use through Class construct. You can see the source code of RS485 Construct and ModbusRTU Construct.
So what you need to do to use the Serial1 is to create an instance of the Class and pass-in the serial port that you are going to use.
#include <ArduinoRS485.h>
#include <ArduinoModbus.h>

#define UART1_TX_PIN PA_9       // J1 header 33 (LPUART) = SERIAL1_TX  = R0
#define UART1_RX_PIN PA_10      // J1 header 35 (LPUART) = SERIAL1_RX   = DI
#define UART1_RTS_PIN PI_14     // J1 header 37 (LPUART) = SERIAL1_RTS  = REn pin
#define UART1_CTS_PIN PI_15     // J1 header 39 (LPUART) = SERIAL1_CTS  = DE

RS485 rs485(Serial1, UART1_TX_PIN, UART1_RX_PIN, UART1_RTS_PIN, UART1_CTS_PIN);
ModbusRTUClient mbClient(&rs485);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // start the Modbus RTU client
  if (!mbClient.begin(9600)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to start Modbus RTU Client!");
    while (1);
  }
}

void loop() {
 // access various ModbusRTUClient methods with the mbClient object
}


Thanks
this worked (almost, i had to make a few changes but it got me there,  i have added the required changes below).   I had attepted a version of this approach before but for some reason i couldnt get it to work.
#include <ArduinoRS485.h>
#include <ArduinoModbus.h>

#define UART1_TX_PIN PA_9       // J1 header 33 (LPUART) = SERIAL1_TX  = R0
#define UART1_RX_PIN PA_10      // J1 header 35 (LPUART) = SERIAL1_RX   = DI
#define UART1_RTS_PIN PI_14     // J1 header 37 (LPUART) = SERIAL1_RTS  = REn pin
#define UART1_CTS_PIN PI_15     // J1 header 39 (LPUART) = SERIAL1_CTS  = DE

// These next two lines are different.
RS485Class rs485(Serial1, UART1_TX_PIN, UART1_RX_PIN, UART1_RTS_PIN);
ModbusRTUClientClass mbClient(&rs485);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // start the Modbus RTU client
  if (!mbClient.begin(9600)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to start Modbus RTU Client!");
    while (1);
  }
}

void loop() {
 // access various ModbusRTUClient methods with the mbClient object
}


RS485Class is not necessary, RS485 should work, see source code. Same for ModbusRTUClient.

Hi and thanks again.  Tried it again, and i can only get the code working when i use RS485Class and ModbusRTUClientClass to define my mbClient obj.
